# How to install TikZ-library from CTAN manually on Debian?

Tags: installing, ctan, debian

On Debian based operating systems the `TikZ`-library named `tikz-relay` should be included in the Debian-package [texlive-pictures](https://packages.debian.org/buster/texlive-pictures). However, I installed `texlive-pictures` on my machine but it seems that I am still missing this package.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

**How can I install this package manually?**

I guess I have to

1. Download the `zip`-file from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-relay)
2. Extract the included `.tex`-file to `usr/local/share/texmf/tikz-relay` or something similar
3. Run `texhash` as root user

That's all?

Comment: it is installed automatically in an up to date texlive, I have it at /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-relay/tex/tikzlibrarycircuits.ee.IEC.relay.code.tex (please post test document as code not an image, then people can check it locally)

Comment: but if you haven't got it it is just a single file take http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-relay/tex/tikzlibrarycircuits.ee.IEC.relay.code.tex and put it in the directory with your document.

Comment: I already send an email to the maintainer of `tikz-relay` that the package isn't correctly shipped by TeXLive and that he should contact them, I'm not sure when it will be corrected, but I think/hope the fix should be deployed some time next week.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you so much guys!